# Every time I try to play on a multiplayer SMP server, I get nothing but an empty blue world. How do I fix this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I go to play on a multiplayer SMP server, I join, it pops me in, and then I fall into nothing and stand on nothing. It's all blue; all I can see is the sun and sky. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it permanently like that? 1.3 has a horrible bug that loads every chunk around you starting from the outermost and finally ending with the chunk you're occupying. It should eventually load the world if you wait long enough.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin - based on the speed of your computer, it could take a couple minutes to fully render what you're standing on.

Comment: It could be your internet. Our server takes roughly 20 seconds to show terrain for new players because they have to download all of the chunks. Try leaving your computer idle for a few minutes to see if anything appears.

Answer (score 8):

This is likely just a slow server/internet connection. Have you tried waiting a few minutes? I find on my connection that some largely built and developed servers with many players such as the Reddit Server, loading the chunks at spawn can take 2 or 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. No matter how long you wait nothing will ever load. You need to close Minecraft and wait a few hours. After that you need to re-open Minecraft and attempt to connect to the server again.

Comment: Can you explain why this works / how you know it works? Without including background justification it sounds like it could just be cargo-cult superstition.